# Is there a way to prevent navigation from standard new record page after save

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

I have a Lightning web component that uses Navigation Mixin to show create new record page for a custom object. I am using the following function for this.

```
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'my__Address__c',
                actionName: 'new',
                my__Account__c: this.recordId
            }
        });
    }
```

All this works fine , once I save the record , the popup window closes and the main page is refreshed to show the newly created record. Is there a way to prevent this default behaviour?